# Instrumenting ILogger to .net core app trace - Dynatrace sink

Tags: c#, distributed, serilog, distributed-transactions, dynatrace

App Environment: Azure, .NET Core 3.1, C#

We understand that Serilog provides a Dynatrace Sink [`Serilog.Sinks.Dynatrace`](https://github.com/iojancode/Serilog.Sinks.Dynatrace) for logging app trace statements to Dynatrace.

We are trying to avoid having a dependency on Serilog in our .NET core app.

Is there any library/nuget that Dynatrace provides that has the necessary sink that can be configured to send in app level trace info to Dynatrace log viewer?

Or, is there a setting/configuration in Dynatrace that allows for enabling OneAgent running on the cloud infrastructure to do it out of the box with no instrumentation?

We are trying to move app trace logging away from Azure App Insights to Dynatrace log viewer.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. You are asking about architecture choice and framework choice. 

There is no "code" to show, because this isn't a coding question, you are on the wrong stack ;)

In my opinion

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/
Try here?

Comment: Hmm... This is a coding question... coding related to .NET Core app services ... adding code for logging from app service trace statements to a log sink provider.  @MortenBork Don't you agree?

Also, I don't see a 'dynatrace' tag in the other softwareengineering.stackexchange.com  you pointed out.  Does it fit there?

Comment: I dont agree for the following reason: 
You aren't showing any attempted work. 
You aren't asking for specific coding advice, you are asking if anyone knows of a framework or a modification to a framework that allows for you to acheive something, you don't know how to do. 
That isn't a coding question, that would be: I have the Ilogger interface, and I am expect ing to see my message in a certain component, but I get the exception -> some exception, together with your code examples etc. You have more than 754 points, you must at one point have read, "How to ask a question"

Comment: There might not be a specific tag for "Dynatrace", but you aren't actually asking a specific question for how to code log info to said framework, you are asking if a framework or a different framework exists, that doesn't have a specific dependency. 
And a dependency in terms of eco-system for a frameworks, doesn't constitute coding. You are simply plugging other coders code. 

If you have specific question as how to do something like that, please be specific, show us what you trying to do with actual code examples from your work, what errors you get. Etc.

Comment: Add, what you expect, in terms of input, output, if you have test cases, then show us those, etc.
Which you either can, and I am wrong, happily so, and we would be able to see what you precisely want to do, or I am right, and you can't because the question you have, isn't directly coding related.

Comment: And By the way, I don't believe that the Ilogger interface from microsoft.Extensions.logging has a dependency on serilog? I mean, you can use serilog with it, but there is no dependency afaik?

Comment: @MortenBork.  

Looks like StackOverflow is getting too complicated.  The question got 'closed' as 'off-topic' on the other board you suggested 

Here it is: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/437508/instrumenting-ilogger-to-net-core-app-trace-dynatrace-sink

You are correct - ILogger interface doesn't have dependency on serilog.  But, we are trying to avoid referencing serilog nuget in our project in order to bring in Dynatrace sink .. looking for a Dynatrace sink related nuget from Dynatrace.

Answer (score 2):

https://github.com/Dynatrace/openkit-dotnet
This is the location of the dynatrace openkit.

I have no idea if Dynatrace enforces a serilog dependency, but if it does, you will find it in here, and then you should be able to write an extension that doesn't rely on it?

Perhaps?

Best option I got. Then at least, the answer is programming related :D